# How to Iterate through rows and append incremental number to duplicates?

Tags: bash, scripting, increment

I have an environment of several hundred autoscaled servers and server host file that gets generated every few minutes, with a row per server with the 3 columns:

eg.

```
10.10.1.2 video-server-usa-01 vs-usa-01
10.10.1.3 video-server-jap-01 vs-jap-01
10.10.1.4 upload-server upload
10.10.1.5 upload-server upload
10.10.1.6 upload-server upload
10.10.1.7 editing-server edit
10.10.1.8 editing-server edit
10.10.1.9 data-storage-server-01 data-01
```

also, the list is random and unsorted.

pretty simple env, so dont want to over-engineer the problem with fancy self-reporting dns or whatever on boot or termination. they're rarely accessed but if so its via a jumpbox, just want that server to always have correct host info and short tagged names for easy connection

servers that are always singular, have a number on the end of them. servers without a number scale up and down all the time, and these are the problem ones, because they all get tagged with the same name.

need to sort the rows, then ignore any row ending with a number, and for any other row where the 3rd column has no number and there are duplicate results, they need a number incremented and appended to the end.

eg. end result:

```
10.10.1.2 video-server-usa-01 vs-usa-01
10.10.1.3 video-server-jap-01 vs-jap-01
10.10.1.4 upload-server upload-01
10.10.1.5 upload-server upload-02
10.10.1.6 upload-server upload-03
10.10.1.7 editing-server edit-01
10.10.1.8 editing-server edit-02
10.10.1.9 data-storage-server-01 data-01
```

Comment: what have you tried?.

Comment: is the file sorted by ip address in the first column?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
$ cat genie1.txt
10.10.1.2 video-server-usa-01 vs-usa-01
10.10.1.8 editing-server edit
10.10.1.6 upload-server upload
10.10.1.3 video-server-jap-01 vs-jap-01
10.10.1.4 upload-server upload
10.10.1.5 upload-server upload
10.10.1.9 data-storage-server-01 data-01
10.10.1.7 editing-server edit

$ sort -k2,3 -k1 -n genie1.txt | perl -F"\s+" -lane ' { if( /(.+?)(?<![0-9])$/) {$k="$F[1] $F[2]";$col3{$k}++; printf("%s %s %s-%02d\n",$F[0],$F[1],$F[2],$col3{$k}) }
else {print} } '
10.10.1.2 video-server-usa-01 vs-usa-01
10.10.1.3 video-server-jap-01 vs-jap-01
10.10.1.4 upload-server upload-01
10.10.1.5 upload-server upload-02
10.10.1.6 upload-server upload-03
10.10.1.7 editing-server edit-01
10.10.1.8 editing-server edit-02
10.10.1.9 data-storage-server-01 data-01

$
```

Comment: thank you, some perl wizardry was exactly the ticket!